# sumset of semi-algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is the sumset of two semi-algebraic sets $A$ and $B$ semi-algebraic?

If not - can we put restrictions on $A$ and $B$ to make the above hold?

For the case that $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact semi-algebraic set and $B=[-1,\  1]^n$ also compact and semi-algebraic the sumset seems to be semi-algebraic. Is that just a too simple example of a semi-algebraic set for $B$. Or is there anything that can be generalized?

Thanks you so much for your help!

Gerome

Comment: The sumset is the image of $A\times B$ by $f(x,y)=x+y$.

Comment: Did you get it from there?

Comment: correct, $A\oplus B=\left\{x|\exists a\in A, \exists b\in B, x=a+b\right\}$

Comment: So, all you need is that cartesian product of semialgebraics is semialgebraic, and that image by polynomial of a semialgebraic is semialgebraic. For the latter, use Tarski-Seidenberg's theorem.

Comment: aaah sorry, I did not get your point. Thanks for your comments - the last one made the penny drop.